# sfValidator Choice is invalid symfony 1.4

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

i'm writing an form code with datas of another form. I'm getting an error from the validators with "choices", the erros says: `dia_semana [Invalid.] id_programa [Invalid.]` but i don't know how to solve this.
This is my code:

```
public function configure()
{        
$this->setWidgets(array(    

$this->validatorSchema->setOption('allow_extra_fields', true);
$this->validatorSchema->setOption('filter_extra_fields', true); 

$this->setWidgets(array(
        'dia_semana'    => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('label' => 'Data da Semana','choices' => array("" => "", "segunda" => "Segunda-Feira","terca" => "Terca-Feira"))),

  'id_programa'   => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('label' => 'Programa',
                                                        'choices' => Doctrine_Core::getTable('tbprogramas_tv')->getProgramas())), 
));
$this->setValidators(array(
        'dia_semana'    => new sfValidatorChoice(array(
'choices' => array("" => "","segunda" => "Segunda-Feira", "terca" => "Terca-Feira"), 'required' => false)),
 'id_programa'   =>  new sfValidatorChoice(array(
            'choices' => array_keys(Doctrine_Core::getTable('tbprogramas_tv')->getProgramas()), 
'required' => false)),
));
}
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

`sfValidatorChoice` uses only values of array as valid values, so instead of `['key' => 'value']` pairs you have to provide only `['key']`:

```
public function configure()
{        
    $this->setWidgets(array(    

    $this->validatorSchema->setOption('allow_extra_fields', true);
    $this->validatorSchema->setOption('filter_extra_fields', true); 

    $dias = array("" => "", "segunda" => "Segunda-Feira","terca" => "Terca-Feira");
    $programas = Doctrine_Core::getTable('tbprogramas_tv')->getProgramas();

    $this->setWidgets(array(
            'dia_semana'    => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('label' => 'Data da Semana','choices' => $dias)),

      'id_programa'   => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('label' => 'Programa',
                                                            'choices' => $programas)), 
    ));
    $this->setValidators(array(
            'dia_semana'    => new sfValidatorChoice(array(
    'choices' => array_keys($dias), 'required' => false)),
     'id_programa'   =>  new sfValidatorChoice(array(
                'choices' => array_keys($programas)), 
    'required' => false)),
    ));

}
```